# Parse Server: hosting MongoDB on AWS vs hosting on MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, mlab

AWS published a [blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk) about migrating from Parse. I wonder why they suggest hosting MongoDB on MongoLab instead of hosting it directly on AWS?

What's the advantage of hosting MongoDB on MongoLab?

Comment: The article you linked specifically says "You have a number of options on where or how to run your MongoDB, including hosting your own instance on AWS either manually or using a service such as, MongoLab to create a setup for you." They are just showing you the easiest option. Installing a Mongo cluster correctly on EC2 with scaling and fail over and automated backups would take up several more blog posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have enough experience to manage mongodb yourself, and scale on your own, i think aws instances are cheaper than any hosted mongodb service. That depends on how many servers you will have to manage based on your requirement. 
And another reason, since parse is a hosted service, that blog post is mostly for people looking for another hosted service.